# Foreign table using EF core

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6

I have a advertiser model like:

```
public class Advertiser
{
    public int AdvertiserId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public Address AddressId { get; set; }
}
```

Inside this class I have a builder as:

```
public class AdvertiserConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Advertiser>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Advertiser> builder)
    {

        builder.ToTable("Advertisers");
        builder.HasKey(x => x.AdvertiserId);
        builder.Property(x => x.Name).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(250);
        builder.HasOne(x => x.AddressId);
    }
}
```

And address model like:

```
public class Address
{
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

So that I want to do is a simple foreign key on the Advertiser table so I check [msdn reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key)

And it says that I should use `HasOne` and `WithMany` methods in order to use `HasForeignKey`, but I do not understand why? it is necessary to use them to do a simple foreign key connection? if yes, what fields should I use on HasOne and WithMany? Thanks!

Comment: https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/fluent-api/hasone-method

Comment: In order to fully configure a valid relationship, it is necessary to follow the Has/With pattern and pair the use of HasOne with either the WithOne or WithMany method, depending on whether the relationship being configured is a one-to-one relationship or a one-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 0):

In ef for a relation you define a "navigation property" on both sides of the related objects and a "foreign key property". So your entities should look like this

```cs
public class Advertiser
{
    public int AdvertiserId { get; set; }
    public Address? Address { get; set; }
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class Address
{
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Advertiser>? Advertisers { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

and your entity configuration

```cs
   builder
      .HasOne(adv => adv.Address)
      .WithMany(adr => adr.Advertisers)
      .HasForeignKey(adv => adv.AddressId);
```

That way you define which properties are the connected objects and how ef should resolve this from the database (by using the foreign key).

Now you can use code like this

```cs
foreach(var advertiser in address.Advertisers)
{
   ...
}

or 

var street = advertiser.Address.Street;
...
```

You won't want to do all the navigation manually by requerying the database e. g. for the connected advertisers after you read an address.

Remember to `Include` navigation properties in your queries, when they will be used after/outside of the queries.